# Routing ubuntu server 20.10

Tags: server, routing, nat

I can't configure routing on my server because of:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q64Gr.png
Have you any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

1 means you enable the routing/port forwarding. 0 means false.